# Dynamically recolor activity background before showing it

Tags: android

I need to set custom color both to actionbar and to client area. With the following code my app get succesfully colored, however, I still see the default theme for like 0.5 seconds when the activity starts. How do I remove this gap?
The color is set dynamically, so I guess I cannot use theme definition here. (I will later change my code to get color from an `Intent`)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_screen);
    setNoteColor(0xFFFFF8DC);
}

public void setNoteColor(int color) {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setBackground(new ColorDrawable(color));
    assert getActionBar() != null;
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(color));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Funny thing I just read about that yesterday... =)

[Here](http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/01/23/android-app-launching-made-gorgeous/) is a great post regarding you issue

Comment: Thank you, but that does not help. As I said, the color is known only at runtime, so I cannot define it in styles or layout xmls. Actually, the first comment to that article describes a very similar problem.